# Are there any built-in methods in Java to increase Font size?

Tags: java, swing

Are there any built-in methods in Java to increase Font size?

Comment: Could you specify for what case do you need to increase the font size?

Answer (score 19):

The [`Font`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) class allows you to specify font size.

So, to create a font you do something like this:

```
Font f = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
```

The `fontSize` parameter will determine the size of your `Font`.

You can't actually change the size of an existing Font object.  The best way to achieve a similar effect is to use the `deriveFont(size)` method to create a new almost identical `Font` that is a different size.

```
Font biggerFont = existingFont.deriveFont(bigNumber);
```

Comment: Note: you need to specify that `bigNumber` is a float, otherwise you'll trigger the `deriveFont(int style)` overload. I.e. `existingFont.deriveFont(100f);`.

Answer (score 15):

You can derive a new Font with a different size by using the following:

```
Font original = // some font
Font bigger = original.deriveFont(newSize);
```

Where newSize is a float, **not** an int.  This is well documented in the JavaDoc for Font as other people have pointed out

Comment: +1. @Raji: In addition, if you want to increase the font size on the GUI components this way you can do it while retaining the font set and format. For example: myLabel.setFont(myLabel.getFont().deriveFont(20)); You can then implement a recursive algorithm which performs this operation on the entire component hierarchy. Just an idea.

Comment: newSize _must_ be a `float`, not an `int`. See [deriveFont(float)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) and answer from Avrom. [deriveFont(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(int)) applies a _style_ (encoded as an `int` value) to the font.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you want to change the font size on a specific `JLabel`, you can do:

```
label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(newSize));
```

Make sure that `newSize` is a `float` not an `int`.

Answer (score 12):

I interpreted this question as "How can I increase font size for Swing across the board." I'm not aware of any built-in way to do this, but you could do it yourself by modifying the values in the UIManager class on startup before you create any Swing components.

I do this by having a parameter passed into my app that I use as a multiplier. If I pass in 150 it'll multiply all existing fonts by 150%. The code is as follows

```
public static void initializeFontSize() {
    String fontSizeParam = System.getProperty("myapp.fontSize");
    if (fontSizeParam != null) {
        float multiplier = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeParam) / 100.0f;
        UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
        int i = 0;
        for (Enumeration e = defaults.keys(); e.hasMoreElements(); i++) {
            Object key = e.nextElement();
            Object value = defaults.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Font) {
                Font font = (Font) value;
                int newSize = Math.round(font.getSize() * multiplier);
                if (value instanceof FontUIResource) {
                    defaults.put(key, new FontUIResource(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), newSize));
                } else {
                    defaults.put(key, new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), newSize));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can set the property *swing.plaf.metal.controlFont* when running you application:

> java -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Dialog-50 YourMainClass

in this example, you set the default font to be "Dialog" with size 50.

Answer (score 3):

The question is way too vague to give a good answer. But I think you want to systematically increase font size in your application.

The font face, style and size in a Java Swing application is controlled via the LookAndFeel mechanism. You need to change the font in the look-and-feel if you want the change to apply to all Swing components of a given type.

Have a look at the [UIManager](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) example.

Here's how to change the font globally for some UI components:

```
UIManager.put("Label.font", new FontUIResource(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10)));
UIManager.put("Button.font", new FontUIResource(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 10)));
UIManager.put("TextField.font", new FontUIResource(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10)));
```